# Does it matter the vector I choose?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

The exercise is:

> Consider the euclidian space $\mathbb{R}^5$ with inner product and the linear subspace $S$ generated by $\left\{(0,1,0,1,0); (1,0,1,1,0); (-1,4,,-1,0,0), (2,-10,2,1,0)\right\}$. Calculate the point from $S$ that is closer to $(0,1,1,1,0)$.

I just have a question: I know that first I need to calculate the projection of the vector $(0,1,1,1,0) \in S$. Does the vector from $S$ that I choose matter? Or is it indifferent?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to project your vector onto the entire subspace, not just one vector.  Use the orthonormal basis you found in your last question and the orthonormal projection formula: $$\operatorname{proj}_W\vec v = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle \vec v, \vec w_i\rangle \vec w_i$$

Comment: @Bye_World Thanks! Is it enough to calculate this projection to find the closest point of S to the vector? I know this is enough to calculate the vector from S closer to (0,1,1,1,0) but I'm doubting if it's enough to calculate the point...

Comment: Yes.  That vector is the point in question.  Or more precisely if $P$ is the point your want then the vector you calculate is $\vec {OP}$ so the point $P=O +\vec{OP}$.  Ignore that last sentence if you haven't studied affine geometry yet.